# Choose $4$ students out $15$ but Andy can only be selected if Jordan is chosen as treasurer. What is the probability of this event happening?

Tags: probability

A committee of four people will be selected among a group of 15 students . The committee will have the following positions: president, secretary, treasurer and marshal. Andy, one of the students , will accept a position in a committee as long as Jordan is selected as the treasurer. What is the probability that Andy serves in a committee? Your answer must be rounded to the nearest hundredth.

In my answer I first found the total ways to select 4 out of 15 students. Next since Jordan takes one position there are three positions left and if one of the three is given to Andy, only two are left. Thus, this equals to:
`(12C2)(3!)/(15C4)`

Comment: Your numerator is correct. But your denominator is missing a factor of $4!$, since there are positions in the committee, hence, ordering matters if you calculate the number of all possible committees.

Comment: His numerator isn't correct though? I got 13C2 instead of 12C2 because Andy and Jordan out of 15 people are chosen, so there are only 13 people left.

Comment: See the comments that I left after the answer of Some Guy.

Comment: Is Jordan known to be a thief?

Answer (score 2):

It is simpler to just compute the *Pr* of **J**ordan as treasurer and **A**ndy in another post in the committee

Thus P($\mathbf J$  in committee)$\cdot$ P($\mathbf J$ gets treasurer post)$\cdot$ P($\mathbf A$ in commitee)

$ = \dfrac4{15}\cdot\dfrac 1 4 \times \dfrac3{14} = \dfrac 1 {70}$

Who and where the rest in the committee are doesn't matter !

Answer (score 1):

First we calculate the number of possible committees. We have $15$ choices for pres, $14$ for secret, $13 $ for treasure, and $12$ for marshal. Thus, the possible committees are $15*14*13*12$. Now, we need to find the number of VALID committees. We know that we need both Andy and Jordan on our committee. We should note that Jordan MUST BE treasurer. So, how do we arrange Andy and two other members amongst president, marshall, and secretary? Well, we have to choose $2$ other members besides out of the remaining $13$. We may do this $13\choose2$ ways. Since there are $3$ positions, we may arrange these members and Andy $3!$ times. Thus, the number of valid committees is $3! {13\choose2}$. The total number of committees is $15*14*13*12$. Thus the probability is $3! {13\choose2} \over 15*14*13*12$. After some cancelations and multiplications, we get $\frac{1}{70}$.

Comment: @meGoesBleh Ignoring the inaccuracy in trancelocation's comment, as indicated by the comment of Some Guy, you should pay close attention to the comment of trancelocation as well as the answer of Some Guy.  Normally, specifying the denominator of $\binom{15}{4}$ in this kind of problem is a good idea.  However, the specification of the denominator **absolutely must always be consistent** with the specification of the numerator.  ...see next comment

Comment: @meGoesBleh Here, because of the constraint that it is pertinent that Jordan specifically serves as treasurer, you are **forced** to have the numerator **distinguish** which person holds which position.  Therefore, since the denominator **must always be consistent with the numerator**, the denominator must be set to $$4! \times \binom{15}{4} ~~\text{rather than}~~ \binom{15}{4}.$$

Comment: @user2661923 note that meGoes is not getting your @ notifications, you must reply to his question. However, if he has posted a reply to my answer, which he hasn't, he would get the notifiers.

Comment: I never knew about this notification limitation - thanks.  I have corrected the oversight with a well placed flagging comment.